# How I can add users in Telegram channels using TLSharp?

Tags: android, xamarin, telegram

I know how to create a new channel using TLSharp, but how I can add users to this channel?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var contacts = new TLVector<TLInputPhoneContact>();
            contacts.lists.Add(new TLInputPhoneContact { first_name = "xxx", last_name = "xxx", phone = "xxx" });
            var req = new TLRequestImportContacts()
            {
                contacts = contacts
            };
            var contact = client.SendRequestAsync<TLImportedContacts>(req).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

replace SendRequestAsync with client.SendRequestAsync so :

```
public async Task<TLUpdates> InviteUserToChannel(TLAbsInputUser user, TLInputChannel channelid)
    {
        TLVector<TLAbsInputUser> u = new TLVector<TLAbsInputUser>();
        u.lists.Add(user);
        var req = new TLRequestInviteToChannel()
        {
            channel = channelid,
            users = u
        };
        var update = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(req);
        return update;
    }
```

Comment: if I want to invite my telegram contacts then what should I do? I mean where can I get the user as TLAbsInputUser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone

```
    public async Task<TLUpdates> InviteUserToChannel(TLAbsInputUser user, TLInputChannel channelid)
    {
        TLVector<TLAbsInputUser> u = new TLVector<TLAbsInputUser>();
        u.lists.Add(user);
        var req = new TLRequestInviteToChannel()
        {
            channel = channelid,
            users = u
        };
        TLUpdates update =  await SendRequestAsync<TLUpdates>(req);
        return update;
    }
```