# telegram private channel unique invite link

Tags: telegram

i create a private channel in telegram. 
i want to know if there is any way to create an unique invite link that i can share to people i want to join my channel. unique like single use.
actually telegram gives you an invite link but its always the same so if i give it to a person he can give it to anyone he wants. i need a method to avoid this. i'd tried some url shortening services to hide the invite link but at the end they still show the iniztial invite link.
any suggestion?

i'd tried http://once.ly/index.html

Comment: if it's purpose is single use, can't you just add them to the group directly?

Comment: the process has to be automatic.

Comment: There seems to be some ways to add contacts to the channel via API. For example see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610203/how-i-can-add-users-in-telegram-channels-using-tlsharp. It might help to automate your user add process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit:

Now you can [generate unique links](https://telegram.org/blog/autodelete-inv2#expiring-invite-links) for different people, and limit how many people can join and change the expiring time!

---

Original answer (2017):

There is **no way** to create a unique invite link at this time.

But if I were you, I would create a bot, send link via bot with inline button, which is default hiding link behind text.

For example, you give your user a link like `t.me/bot?start=channel_link`, and when your bot received `/start channel_link`, send a message with [inline button](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) with `url` parameter.

Comment: yes. i think thats the safest method. im going to give a single use unique code to the person i want o give access to the channel. so they input that code to the bot who control if the code is valid and in case responde with an inline button.

Comment: are you aware if a bot can generate such links?

Comment: nevermind, found the solution and added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this one from the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking).

```html
<a href="https://t.me/botname_bot?start=vCH1vGWJxfSeofSAs0K5PA">start=channel_link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now this is possible using tg bots: the [createchatinvitelink](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createchatinvitelink) endpoint is available and has `member_limit` param. Set the latter to `1` and the link becomes "unique".